# reload whole html page without loading js/css files

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I reload html page without loading all included js/css files.
I can see YII php framework can do it somehow but couldn't catch how.
when I try to reload page like $(document).load('/'); page blinks and I can see in Chrome developer tools it loads all js/css too and page blinks and reloads.
When yii do same there's no page blink and I can see only 1 request with full source of page started with

Could you advice please
Thanks

Comment: If you have to do this, you're probably doing something else that's terrible wrong, as reloading the entire page with ajax, which is what load() is a shortcut for, is generally not a very good idea.

Comment: load your partially page with ajax.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish?  As stated before this is a bad idea.

Comment: How can php framework do anything in browser? makes no sense

Comment: I just gave example of framework that can do it. I tried to do the same and no luck.  PHP YII framework uses pure js or jquery to do it in browser.
I tried to load content of whole page this way $(document).html(...)
and it didn't work. all js/css loads.